# Is there a way to create a circular file storage ? like syslog in linux

Tags: ios, circular-buffer

In my iOS application, I want to store some messages that I obtain from my remote server. However, instead of storing these messages forever, I want to purge, once I have a N number of messages; i.e., if my N is configured to be 10, I want to store 10 messages and on the arrival of the 11th message, I want to delete the 1st message.

Is there a standard way to do this in iOS ? I am yet to write the code to saving the messages, so choosing any method of saving is fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your messages in a file. After you get the message read your file's messages to an NSMutableArray, replace the most old message with new one and overwrite your file with new array data.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is a straight fwd way.

The way I would do is have a table using SQLLite. Have 2 columns id(int, autoincrement), value(String). When inserting, if max(id) >=10 delete row with min(id) and insert the new value.

Ofcourse, this woud fail after it reached MAX_INT_VALUE. So if you thing you would never get to this value you are good.